Nextjs middleware file is not executing anything
Okay so I was working with NextJs implementing NextAuth for a page that's supposed to be accessed by admin only. Then, I was introduced to the new concept of the "middleware.ts" file, which apparently should execute a function for every determined route.
But it is not working for me for some reason, check this out, I removed everything, and only kept a small console log just to know if the file is running, but it doesn't seem to log anything to the browser inspect or the terminal.
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("MIDDLEWARE EXECUTED FROM: ", request.url);

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
};


And yes, the file name is middleware.ts, located in the root directory.
please help if you can I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days.

You cannot use console.log in a middleware.tsx or TS file since this file is meant to run on server side, although you can debug the file in vscode

Never mind, my problem was that I had to take the middleware file to "/src" not the root directory. thanks everyone <3

If you're implementing NextAuth and want to add middleware functions. In the middleware.ts you can add some code like this for example
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

function removeContentLengthIfTransferEncoding(req: NextRequest) {
  if (req.headers.get("transfer-encoding")) {
    req.headers.delete("content-length");
  }
}

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    removeContentLengthIfTransferEncoding(req);

    const value = req.nextauth.token;
    if (!value && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin/")) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/login", req.url));
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      async authorized({ token }) {
        if (!token) {
          return false;
        }

        // // `/me` only requires the user to be logged in
        return !!token;
      },
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },
  },
);

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/root/:path*"],
};

If you implement middleware outside of the next-auth there will be two middleware work in the same time. References you can read on
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs
